# For which values of $k$ are the vectors linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have the following set:

$S = \{1+kx, k + x + x^2 + x^3, kx^2 + x^3 \}$

I need to find the values of $k$ when those vectors are linearly independent.

I would calculate the determinant and set it equal to zero but this is not a square matrix so this approach is impossible (I guess).

What are the other possible ways of tackling this problem?

Comment: supposing your set $\{1,x,x^2, x^3\}$ is linearly independent, you should write this out with the 'hyper vector'  $V := \bigg[\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} 1 & x & x^2 & x^3\end{array}\bigg]$ then $VA = \bigg[\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} 1+kx &k +x +x^2 + x^3& kx^2 +x^3  \end{array}\bigg] $.  Explicitly write out $A$ and figure our what values of $k$ imply it has full column rank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Row reduction gives
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1&k&0&0 \\ k&1&1&1 \\ 0&0&k&1 \end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix} 1&k&0&0 \\ 0&1-k^2&1&1 \\ 0&0&k&1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
which has rank $3$ if $k^2\ne1$.

If $k=1$, then 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1&k&0&0 \\ 0&1-k^2&1&1 \\ 0&0&k&1 \end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix} 1&k&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&1 \\ 0&0&1&1 \end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix} 1&k&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&1 \\ 0&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
which has rank $2$.

If $k=-1$, then
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1&k&0&0 \\ 0&1-k^2&1&1 \\ 0&0&k&1 \end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix} 1&k&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&1 \\ 0&0&-1&1 \end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix} 1&k&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&1 \\ 0&0&0&2 \end{bmatrix}
$$
which has rank $3$.

Bottom line: the vectors are linearly independent iff the rank is $3$ iff $k\ne1$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $$c_1(1+kx)+c_2( k + x + x^2 + x^3)+c_3( kx^2 + x^3)=0$$

The coefficients of powers of $x$ must be $0$

Thus $$ c_2+c_3=0, c_2+kc_3=0, c_1+c_2k=0, c_1k+c_2=0$$

Note that if $k\not=1$ then the above conditions imply that $$c_1=c_2=c_3 =0$$

Therefore for linear independence of the vectors we need to have $k\not =  1$

Comment: Darn it, my university sucks, I guess they made typo and actually asked for linearly DEPENDENT set. Because the "correct" result is k = 1. Thanks for making this clear anyway. If k = 1 we get a zero row which implies linear dependency.

Comment: when $k=-1$ they are independent.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use determinants, here’s one way. The vectors are linearly dependent iff the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix} 1&k&0&0 \\ k&1&1&1 \\ 0&0&k&1 \end{bmatrix}$$ is rank-deficient. This in turn is equivalent to all of its $3\times3$ minors vanishing. Computing the appropriate determinants produces the following system of equations: $$k-k^2 = 0 \\ 1-k = 0 \\ 1-k^2 = 0 \\ k-k^3 = 0.$$ The only solution is $k=1$.